# Replace fragment based on position of list item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm using a 2 line list view for my fragment. How can I perform the necessary procedures based on the position of the list view item that was selected? Below is code to replace the detail fragment but it's not position related.

- If mTwoPane is true, I want the detail container to be replaced with a fragment (using the fragment name within that list item)
- If mTwoPane is false, I want the activity to be launched (using the activity name within that list item)

**Replacing the detail container**

```
                FragmentLineChooserList newFragment = new FragmentLineChooserList();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentMainList.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                transaction.commit();
```

**FragmentWCLine.java**

```
public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ListView listView;

    private class WC {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static WC[] mWC;

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);

        mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };

        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].fragmentClass));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].activityClass));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        WC[] mWC;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
            this.mWC = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mWC.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mWC[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentWCLine - Update 0**

```
public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ListView listView;

    private class WC {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static WC[] mWC;

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);

        mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };

        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].fragmentClass));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].activityClass));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        WC[] mWC;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
            this.mWC = samples;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mWC.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mWC[position];
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentWCLine - Update 1**

```
public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
ListView listView;

private class WC {
    private CharSequence station;
    private CharSequence zone;
    private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
    private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

    public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
        this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
        this.activityClass = activityClass;
        this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
        this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
    public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
}

private static WC[] mWC;

private boolean mTwoPane;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);

    mWC = new WC[]{
            new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
            new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
    };

    listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
    listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mTwoPane) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].fragmentClass));
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].activityClass));
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}

static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView station;
        TextView zone;
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    WC[] mWC;

    public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
        this.mWC = samples;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mWC.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mWC[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
            viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
        viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());
        return convertView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am not understanding fully on what is not working. Is it not taking the value of position in onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position...?

Comment: Is there a reason why mWC is declared as static? I m guessing you just want it to be a singleton but what other reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice one issue in code `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts)` in `MyAdapter` constructor. It should not reside in this method. I have never seen any sample projects do this in a constructor. The reason is if the user flips the phone or Android decides to swap out your app to release memory, the constructor is not reinstated. Test it out.

Code suggestion, inflate in **getView**:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(contexts).inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
...
}
```

NEW code suggestion:

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Notes:

- Get `contexts` from the constructor and save it for getView().
- I notice you defined `getItemId`() and return 0 in the adapter instead of an actual value like position or a member variable of mWC[position]. If this method return 0 or null, any code referencing it will get confused with the zero value.
- The code for `getItemId` is copied from the same method in ArrayAdapter.

Comment: OK, I've just removed:


`@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;}` and `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);`


What else do I need to get rid of and add to the java file?

Comment: @MacaronLover, For now, that's all. I noticed you got some compile errors. We, the readers and I, did not know that important information before.

Comment: @MacaronLover, I reviewed BaseAdapter and a sample code of getItemId(). And it seems it is safer to add code for getItemId since you're extending BaseAdapter. Hence I edited my post to add sample code for this method under word NEW.  FYI, I normally extend ArrayAdapter because I think it's easier.

Comment: Cool. Just 2 errors remain. Code and screenshots above have been updated. I've never used ArrayAdapter before however for this kind of scenario. In order to agree with your difficulty beliefs regarding ArrayAdapter, I would need to see some code first to see if it really is.

Comment: @MacaronLover, I think it's fine to stay with BaseAdapter, most of SO developers chose ArrayAdapter like me. But I don't see a problem with it. Certainly your issue is not related to that.

Comment: Right. Maybe my 2 latest screenshots would give you a better understanding of the errors.

Comment: @MacaronLover, Just to be clear, are you stuck on these compile errors? Next time, it would be good to explain the compile errors and which code. It's hard to see the code and errors. I hope this is not hard to fix. If so, be ready to post another SO question for this since this is NOT even part of the original posted question.

Comment: @MacaronLover, I tried the compile errors on "mWC = new WC[]{.." and it is fine for me. Perhaps you should post the full code for WCWATActivity.class. I do not understand your error message. It seems the compiler is saying that that class is more complicated than expected. Maybe you should add another post for this one.

Comment: Compiling has been fixed. Within the code under **Replacing the detail container**, the top line needs to be changed but I don't know what to.

Comment: @MacaronLover, I don't understand. Where is the code for "transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container..." placed in? Maybe you should update the code in your post and remove code that no longer exists in your app. Basically since ur problem may be code flow, you have to show the relevant code clearly.

Comment: I've put it in a new question: [link to new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683131/unable-to-find-code-to-replace-detail-fragment-based-on-list-item-position)